# What is the datatype (class) of class's name in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the data type of a class name? Or in right terms what is the class of this constant? Is constant a class or a module in ruby?

```
class Abc 
end
```

What is `Abc`?

Comment: `Abc` is a constant but it's also a class and therefore a module and an object :-)

Comment: @Stefen can u please share some reference, because many other comments are contradicting this.

Comment: Sure: `defined? Abc #=> "constant"` and `Abc.is_a? Class #=> true` and `Abc.is_a? Module #=> true` and `Abc.is_a? Object #=> true`

Comment: Maybe this helps: "Stefan" is a name. But "Stefan" is also a person (me) and therefore a human and thus a mammal.

Comment: got it. ur previous comment explained it perfect.

Comment: Your code block is equivalent to the assignment `Abc = Class.new {}`.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the data type of a class name?

What do you mean by "class name"? Classes don't really have names in Ruby. Classes have a [`name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-name) method that returns a human-readable name for the class as a [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html).

> Or in right terms what is the class of this constant? Is constant a class or a module in ruby?

Neither. Constants aren't objects in Ruby, therefore, they don't have a class. (This is the same as in pretty much every other language.)

> What is `Abc`?

A constant which references an object of class `Class`.

By the way: I noticed that you used the terms "type" and "class" interchangeably, but they are not. Types and classes are different things.

Comment: "Abc is a constant which references an object of class Class." Does this mean that Abc constant holds the object reference of class Class?

Comment: No. `Abc` holds the reference to an object that is an *instance of* the `Class` class.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the data type of this constant i.e.-string, integer.

class is an instance of class `Class`.

You can check it (as with any other object, just call `.class` on it):

```
Abc.class
#=> Class
```

> Is constant a class or a module in ruby ?

Neither. Constant is a constant. Constant has assigned value.

Comment: So, is Constant an independently defined entity in ruby?

Comment: @ancho exactly, just like "variable".

Comment: The class of a class is `Class`. The class of a class name is usually `String`, sometimes `Symbol`.

Comment: @Andrey can u please share some reference, because some comments are contradicting and making it difficult to understand

Comment: @ancho none of the comments are contradicting :) class of class is `Class`. sawa says, that class **name** is a `String` (you can check it with `Abc.name.class`) :)

Comment: @sawa When you say _class name_, are you referring to the constant? In which case how can a constant have a class unless it's an object?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: No, he is referring to the return value of [`Module#name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-name), which is `String`.

Comment: @sawa _"sometimes `Symbol`"_ – it can be `nil` for anonymous classes / modules, but `Symbol`?

Comment: @Stefan Depends on what method you are using to get it. Afterall, it's just something extracted from the class, not something that exists beforehand.